# Facebook: publish stream from webcam/file

Tags: facebook, video-capture

Are there any facebook means(api/dialogs) that allow to publish video/photo from webcam? Or recording file to server(using flash) and then using FB.ui stream.publish method is the only way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's a few ways you can do this, and the way you choose ultimately depends on what you need to do.

1. If you want to *stream live video* from the webcam, you'll need to either install software on the client's machine, or record from the cam with flash via your website.  In order to publish live video to Facebook (and actually *stream* it *live*) you'll only be able to publish a feed story with the `FB.ui` JS SDK call, or if you have the `publish_stream` [extended permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/), you could use any server-side SDK to publish a feed story via the Graph API.
2. If you want the user to record a video and then save it to Facebook the client implementation is pretty much the same.  You'll have to install client-side software to record video then upload it, or use Flash via your website to have the user record it and save it on your server.  After you have a copy of the video, you can [upload it via the Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/) using one of the server-side SDKs.  You will also need the [user_videos](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) extended permission to upload these types  of videos.

You could also do a combination of the two.  If you're going to let users stream videos, you make the video player end-point the same to watch a live video as the one to watch the saved version of that video.  Once the video is complete, you can upload a copy of it to Facebook.

Comment: That's all I wanted to know. Thank you very much.